# Search "*" as a string in Netbeans Find option

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I want to search the files containing "*" as a text in my project.

I am using netbeans IDE.

When I do this going to find option in the project it returns all the data and not specfic where "*" is found.
It considers * as any word.

Does anyone have idea of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file search it will work as it is with `*`

In project search you search for `\*` and it will look for `*`

When you do search for `*` it assumes it as a reg.ex and matches to all.So you will have to use escape `\`

Answer (score 0):

Use `\*`. This escapes the `*` and treats it as a regular character.